# Remove Extra Spaces Before and After javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

```
var $one = $('#oneClueShow');
    var x = $("#clueOneInput").find('input[type=text]').val();
    if(x == 'D R' || x == 'd r'|| x == 'D r'|| x == 'd R'|| x == 'd'|| x == 'r' || x == 'd R' || x == 'T A')
```

Above is a snippet of java/ I have. What it does is takes an input  -- then checks for a match. The bug I'm looking to resolve is if there are spaces after or before it isn't recognized.

For example within the input someone can type 'D R' no problem. If a space is added like so 'D R ' then it no longer recognizes the input.

Is there something I can do to affect the input to ensure no space before/after prior to button click? I've been looking into replace, but can't seem to get it going.

A reference for what I've been looking at : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [$.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

```
$.trim(yourstring)
```

which will allow for cross browser compatibility

In your case it would be

```
var x = $.trim($("#clueOneInput").find('input[type=text]').val());
```

Comment: My string or the input string?

Comment: @user3135730 the string that you want to remove the whitespace before and after

Comment: Might want to mention that this requires [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: @ScottGress i assumed he already has it because he tagged jQuery :P

Comment: I do have it already. I'm just trying to figure out the trim relationship here. In relation to at which point a trim would need to take place. At the input or below is what I'm trying to figure out I think. Thanks for this info. D R ect are my set variables and not the input. If that makes sense

Comment: @user3135730 I updated my answer to show you where to trim - you would want to trim it there so you don't have to trim inside the if statement

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ it looks as if ie8 is working. I haven't found any reference to say otherwise. Is this something that you have experienced before?

Comment: nope - it should work with no problem

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method

Example:

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

This will output :

> Hello World!

```js
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use the [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method.

Comment: support isn't in all browsers - but that's just mostly IE8 and lower

Answer (score 3):

Do this for cross-browser:

```
var x = $("#clueOneInput").find('input[type=text]').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

Comment: Amit I'm not sure I understood what you meant by your comment. Can you expand?

Comment: @user3135730, I meant this was a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a check before-hand:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Will enable `.trim` in non-supported browsers. And then, you can use it like:

```
 var x = $("#clueOneInput").find('input[type=text]').val().trim();
```

With the benefit that you can use this `.trim` method at many other places in the code too.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use $.trim() while comparing the string. You can use $.trim() like:

```
  if($.trim(x) == 'D R' || $.trim(x) == 'd r'|| $.trim(x) == 'D r'|| $.trim(x) == 'd R'|| $.trim(x) == 'd'|| $.trim(x) == 'r' || $.trim(x) == 'd R' || $.trim(x) == 'T A')
```